Kubuntu 23.10 doesn't show disk
I have 2 disks. I have my system on sda, and it appears but instead of my second disk I see loop0, loop1 etc. Second disk file system is NTFS. Second disk appears at BIOS and another computer with Windows. Please help

Does this answer your question? Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation
